# CodeIgniter doesn't display errors (PHP dipslay_error already set to On)

Tags: php, codeigniter, centos7

I'm moving a website from a very old server (OVH Release 3) to a fresh installed Webmin on CentOS 7. The website is written in CodeIgniter.

When I open the website, it show only few PHP notices (few deprecated functions). There is no errors, but the websites's content isn't displayed.

On php.ini, display_errors and display_startup_errors are already set on On. Also, error_reporting is E_ALL (phpinfo() function confirmed it).

On CodeIgniter config, environment mode is already on development.

But I did'nt found how to show errors.

My PHP version is 5.6.25.

Comment: Enable error/debugging log.

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: Check [here](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/config.php#L194-L216).

Comment: $config['log_threshold'] = 4; but still no error showing and nothing in log file.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happen because the codeigniter's folder **application/logs/** don't have write permission.

Comment: chmoded 777 to all CodeIgniter folder. Still same problem.

Comment: have you checked if codeigniter has written something in today's log: **.../application/logs/log-2018-02-02.php**?

Answer (score 0):

I think in your root folder `index.php` has environment as `'production'` or something else, so set it to `'development'` then it will display your errors on screen.

Your `index.php` should be as below:

```
/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * APPLICATION ENVIRONMENT
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * You can load different configurations depending on your
 * current environment. Setting the environment also influences
 * things like logging and error reporting.
 *
 * This can be set to anything, but default usage is:
 *
 *     development
 *     testing
 *     production
 *
 * NOTE: If you change these, also change the error_reporting() code below
 */

define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * ERROR REPORTING
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * Different environments will require different levels of error reporting.
 * By default development will show errors but testing and live will hide them.
 */
switch (ENVIRONMENT)
{
    case 'development':
        error_reporting(-1);
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    break;
    case 'testing':
    case 'production':
        ini_set('display_errors', 0);
        error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT & ~E_USER_NOTICE & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED);
    break;
    default:
        header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
        echo 'The application environment is not set correctly.';
        exit(1); // EXIT_ERROR
}
```

above code is as it is as codeigniter provides, what i have changed is the
`ENVIRONMENT` constant to `development` as:

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development')
```